# Kentico CMS - How to differentiate between the same BizForm on two pages?

Tags: c#, kentico

I have two landing pages with the same exact BizForm. How can I tell if a user has submitted the form on page A vs. page B - testing page design effectivness? I want to keep the BizForm exactly the same; otherwise, I'll end up with a bunch of forms to manage. I don't have access to the web part code, so it would have to be a solution I can do through the CMS GUI.

Using Kentico v5.5.

Comment: I have no idea what Kentico is, but can't you add a hidden input field for example, that defines the origin of the form (`origin=landingPageA` vs `origin=landingPageB`), which you set (e.g. according to the URL or controller or whatever) when the form is requested? Or does this require changing the web part?

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't know how to add it with Kentico's BizForm web part. And even if I did know how to, the change would be replicated on across pages. I need a way to somehow make a change to the BizForm at the web page level. I really hate this CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at using an Alternative Form. It's basically a copy of the same BizForm, and you can modify/change a few of the fields. Create one extra field on the BizForm, and assign the value of it based on which form you're using (main or alternate). Just don't display the value on the form itself.

Then, on the page, specify whether to use the main BizForm, or the Alternative BizForm.

Comment: Is that a feature of a newer version of Kentico? I'm stuck with v5.5.

Comment: Nevermind - I figured it out. Thanks for your suggestion to use an Alternative Form. I didn't know that was an option!! I've just added a label to the main form with value of A and changed the label on the alternative form to B. Works great, and it properly shows in the Data tab. I've been trying to figure this out for two days!